# How to create data service with local transport using proxy?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created data service using WSO2 DSS which is called by proxy service.
Everything works smoothly, but this DSS service is also visible to internet.

Now I would like to hide this DSS so proxy service is so only way to use this service.
Proxy has security, logging etc.

As far as I understand local transport is good and efficient way to keep
traffic between services internal on WSO2.

Everything goes as expected but when I try to set WSDL URL or internal for proxy (which is DSS service WDSL) I get error "Unable to modify proxy service :: Unable to modify proxy service: mylogtest-ProxyServiceAdminProxyAdminException".

In log file there is error "Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error building service from WSDL" and "Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: there is no service with ports to pick".

I get this error when I have local transport only in DSS.
If I add http transport, everything works. Proxy has http and https transports.

Answer (score 0):

Local transport works only inside a single JVM. I guess here you are running DSS and ESB separately i.e. with two jvm instances - if so it won't work. The solution is to install DSS features inside the ESB and then run it (without running the DSS separately). You can find the feature installation guide here: http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Installing+Features+via+the+UI

Comment: I have ESB + DSS running on same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly formed WSDL for proxy. Very novice error.